# method of characteristics implicit equation for u?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Trying to understand how method of characterists is implemented here[ [Method of Characteristics, Quasilinear pde](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215042/method-of-characteristics-quasilinear-pde]) as given in the second solution

why does $x=f(u^t)+u(e^t-1)$

imply $u=e^{-t}F(x+u(1-e^t))$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation in that answer is indeed a little confusing. $f$ is a function which takes the initial value of the function $u_0$ to the $x$-coordinate where that value begins propagating, $x_0$. The initial condition is $u_0=-\frac{x}{2}$, so there is a bijection between the starting points $x_0$ and the point-wise initial values $u_0$. $f$ is the bijection $f:u_0\mapsto x_0$.

Once that is clear, they compute
$$
x = f(ue^t)+u[e^t-1],
$$
which becomes
$$
f(ue^t)=x-u[e^t-1]=x+u[1-e^t].
$$
Now, because $f$ is a bijection, there exists a bijective inverse, $f^{-1}$. **Call this inverse** $F$, and take $F$ of the last line, obtaining
$$
ue^t=F(x+u[1-e^t]),
$$
or
$$
u=e^{-t}F(x+u[1-e^t]).
$$

I hope that helps!